# Recursive conversion of jpeg files

Tags: bash, shell, recursive

I use this commandline to convert jpegs to pdfs inside a folder.

```
for f in *.jpg; do  echo "Converting $f"; convert "$f" "$(basename "$f" .jpg).pdf"; done
```

However, I would like to convert all .jpg from several folders to .pdf located inside the samefolder. I need a bash command which says "go inside folder A, launch the conversion to pdf and when it is done, go to folder B and do the same".

Also jpeg file could be ended by .jpg or .JPG.

My folder structure is such as:

```
Folder A
    File1.jpg
    File1.jpg
    File1.jpg
    File1.jpg
    File1.jpg
Folder B
    File1.jpg
    File1.jpg        
    File1.jpg
    ...
```

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: You would use `find` with the `-execdir` action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated to allow file names `*.jpg` and `*.JPG` according to updated question:
Use `-iname` for case insensitive comparison, and variable expansion with pattern `${file%.[jJ][pP][gG]}`. This will actually match `.jpg` in any capitalization, e.g. `.JpG`.

Assuming `Folder A` and `Folder B` are in the current directory and you want to do the same in all directories recursively:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg | while read -r file
do
    echo "Converting $file"
    convert "$file" " ${file%.[jJ][pP][gG]}.pdf"
done
```

Or if you want to specify the directory names

```
find "Folder A" "Folder B" type f -iname \*.jpg | ...
```

If you don't have any subdirectories named `*.jpg` you can leave out the `-type f`.

If you don't want to do the conversion recursively in subdirectories of `Folder A` etc. you might have to add a `-maxdepth` condition.

Comment: Thanks, but I have this error : `$ find . -type f -name \*.JPG | while read -r file ; do  echo "Converting $f"; convert "$f" "$(basename "$f" .JPG).pdf"; done
Converting *.JPG
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.JPG': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `*.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.`

Comment: What does the `while read -r file`?

Comment: @ppr Please check the variable names. You mixed `file` and `f`. In my proposal I used `"${file%.jpg}.pdf"` instead of calling `basename` because basename would strip the directory name. Do you want to find `*.JPG` in capitals only or both `*.jpg` and `*.JPG`? Please edit your question to add more information. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Indeed, I mixed file and f, sorry. It works now. I have .jpg and .JPG (I updated my question about that).

Comment: I don't remember: is it normal to have single paged pdf output (and not multi-paged)?

Answer (score 4):

What you have asked for is not a recursive operation, so it can be handled by a trivial adaptation of your original code:

```
for f in */*.jpg */*.JPG; do echo "Converting $f"; convert "$f" "${f%.*}.pdf"; done
```

If this is for production code rather than a quick one-off I would protect the possibility that there were no `jpg` or `JPG` files, or that the PDF had already been generated. Add or tweak to your satisfaction, of course:

```
for f in */*.jpg */*.JPG
do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ ! -f "${f%.*}.pdf" ]]
    then
        echo "Converting $f"
        convert "$f" "${f%.*}.pdf"
    fi
done
```

Comment: and given the recent edit to the question, just change both "jpg" to "JPG"

Comment: Is it supposed to make multipage pdfs ? I obtained single paged pdfs.

Comment: @ppr it creates one pdf per image, just as you asked.